# eclipse call hierarchy incomplete

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo, call-hierarchy

When I execute a call hierarchy (Eclipse Indigo) the results I receive are fewer than I know exist.  Strange thing is this functionality seemed to be working only a few weeks ago.

When I run the same operation on the same workspace in Juno I get the call hierarchy results I expect.

Does Eclipse auto-update under the covers?  What else might cause this?

Comment: What part of the call hierarchy is missing?  Were other projects added to the workspace since it last worked?

Comment: The callers are missing.  The callees seem to be working.  No other projects were added to the workspace.